# Retrieving roles from token in an Azure function app using AAD as identity provider

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-identity

I have a working setup in Azure where a Function App is protected by OAuth using an app registration in AAD.

In this app registration, I have defined two roles; *Administrator* and *Developer*. I have assigned both of these roles to myself, and now I want to retrieve the role to determine what kind of actions a user is allowed to take.

To try to understand what is going in, I've added the following to a protected endpoint:

```cs
[FunctionName("Test")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, CancellationToken ct)
{
    bool isDeveloper = req.HttpContext.User.HasClaim("roles", "Developer");
    bool isAdministrator = req.HttpContext.User.HasClaim("roles", "Administrator");
    _logger.LogInformation($"Has role developer? {isDeveloper}"); // true
    _logger.LogInformation($"Has role administrator? {isAdministrator}"); // true

    bool isDeveloperBuiltin = req.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Developer");
    bool isAdministratorBuiltin = req.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Administrator");
    _logger.LogInformation($"Has role developer using built in? {isDeveloperBuiltin}"); // false
    _logger.LogInformation($"Has role administrator using built in? {isAdministratorBuiltin}"); // false
    foreach (Claim claim in req.HttpContext.User.Claims)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(claim.Type + " : " + claim.Value + "\n");
    }
}
```

The name of the role claim in my token is `roles` but under the hood the `IsInRole` function checks the claim [`ClaimsType.Role`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes.role?view=net-6.0) which I do not have in my token. Pasting my token at [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) shows:

```json
"roles": [
    "Developer",
    "Administrator"
]
```

How come the role claim is different for a token issued by Microsoft themselves? Am I misunderstanding something here?

If possible I would like to use the utility method `IsInRole`, but I have worked around this for the moment and wrote a small utility which basically does the same:

```cs
public bool IsUserInRole(ClaimsPrincipal principal, Role role)
{
    return principal.HasClaim("roles", role.ToString());
}
```

However, I would like to understand what is going on here and what steps I could take to use the `IsInRole` method instead. Am I doing something wrong by instead using my own utility method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation of Azure function. You can read about discussion at [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3898) github issue. So your current approach is way to go. However,

I would suggest to write an extension method (may be I like as it is more cleaner).

```
public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtensions
{
   public static bool IsUserInRole(this ClaimsPrincipal principal, Role role)
   {
    return principal.HasClaim("roles", role.ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion looks better! Thanks for the link, I will start to follow that issue. I had the same issue in a Blazor application but I got it to work there using some glue and a `UserAccountFactory` so I thought something similar could work here. This is what I followed for Blazor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/azure-active-directory-groups-and-roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-user-account